# Differentiate between scroll and swipe in Flex Mobile Application

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop, gestures

Is it possible to differentiate between a Horizontal Swipe gesture and a Horizontal Scroll in Flex Mobile.
I have a List (horizontal layout) with no listener attached to it, and a view, with a GestureSwipe listener attached to it, when I try to scroll the list the swipe gesture gets fired, obviously.
I have tried to add a gesture event listener to the list and call a function with event.stopPropagation() which does stop the gesture being fired in the view, but as the list takes up 85% of the screen real-estate this makes it quite difficult to make the view event fire, which defeats the object of what I want to do.

Is there a way to tell the 2 actions apart, speed, duration or something else?

Using FlashDevelop, and Flex SDK v4.14.1, Air 17.0, building for Android

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I can't find out how to differentiate between the 2 events, however there seems to be a workaround, not a good one, but I suppose it could work, however I see an issue with adding the event listener after the list has scrolled to it's furthest point, you would require another scroll/swipe action to make the view transition, not a good experience for the users.

```
list.scroller.viewport.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE,propertyChangeHandler );

protected function propertyChangeHandler(event:PropertyChangeEvent):void
{
    if (event.property == "horizontalScrollPosition" )
    {
        if (event.newValue == (event.currentTarget.measuredWidth - event.currentTarget.width )) {
                navigator.pushView(view.RightView);
        }
        if(event.newValue == 0){
                navigator.pushView(view.LeftView);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: I had a thought that I may be able to just manually dispatch the TransformGestureEvent.GestureSwipe in the conditional above, but I can't set the OffsetX or OffsetY when I try that.

Answer (score 0):

I never developed Flex Mobile, but you can differentiate between a Horizontal Swipe gesture and a Horizontal Scroll if you could override `interceptOnTouchEvent` to get the event;

Comment: This is something I don't think I can do in Flex, and I don't appear to be able to find anyone else asking the same question.
To be honest I can't even think of the difference between a Horizontal Scroll and a GestureSwipe, in both you touch the screen on the right and slide to the left (for this example).
I would have liked to think that maybe not taking your finger off the screen immediately implied it was a scroll, but alas I appear to be mistaken.

I will see if I can find a method based on your suggestion and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @Shaine Fisher can you use the touch down point position to determine which gesture will be triggered ?

Comment: If I set MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT then AIR dispatches mouse and touch events, but not gesture events. Which would kill all my GestureSwipe events, which appear in every view.
When I use MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE, then I do not get the detail about the touch point, I just get the dispatching component and the direction.

Comment: The bottom of the issue is that a Flex Mobile List does not have a scroll event to listen to, so I cannot catch a scroll event at the list level, they are both being determined as a swipe and caught at the view level with the gestureSwipeHandler function.

Argghh (yes I know not very technical, but rather good at relieving stress)